# How to allow a new user to reset password?

Tags: django

I create a new user and specify a password for that user:

```
user = User(username = username, email = email)
user.set_unusable_password()
user.save()
```

When this new user tries to reset password, they get an error:

> The user account associated with this e-mail address cannot reset the password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_unusable_password` sets a value that will never be a valid password hash, and makes the password unchangable by user himself.

I think you should generate a complicated password (using [`make_random_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password)) and send a link for reseting password to the user.